# Displaying code in a scroll box

Tags: html

I am building a website for my resume, both for me and a class. I have some websites that I made for other classes and would like to add those as my portfolio. I would like to include the code, but I don't want a bunch of screen shots of the code, so I would like to put it in a scroll box. The problem is it displays a website inside a scroll box instead of just the code. Is there a way I can make a scroll box that will display html tags and ignore their effects?

Comment: Try this - http://prismjs.com/

Comment: Is this scroll box a: scrolling div, iframe, textarea, or something I haven't suggested here?

Comment: Try http://prismjs.com/ or https://github.com/google/code-prettify It will automatically make your code  to ignore the actual effect of the html tags etc..

Comment: question like recommend me solution

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `<code></code>` tag or `<pre></pre>` tag. Also you have to use javascript to display html tags. Here is a function:

```
String.prototype.escapeHTML = function () {                                        
  return(                                                                 
    this.replace(/>/g,'&gt;').
         replace(/</g,'&lt;').
         replace(/"/g,'&quot;')
  );
};
var codeEl = document.getElementById('myelement');
if (codeEl) {
  codeEl.innerHTML = codeEl.innerHTML.escapeHTML();
}
```

And HTML like this.

```
<pre id="myelement">
<html>my html begins here</html>
</pre>
```